# Mantaflow fluid does not take the shape of a sphere (Blender 2.8)

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I created a sphere and set it up as a container for Mantaflow Fluid. I created another sphere and set it up as an inflow object. No matter what I do and how I play with the values, I can't seem to get the fluid take the shape of the sphere, it only takes the shape of a cube. Seems that it only takes the shape of the bounding box of the container.

Attached are the parameters I'm using, if ever needed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get regular fluid inside a rather spherical container or .... rather fantasy water sphere with a more magical effect?

Answer (score 7):

The container/domain will always use the bounding box of the object (the cube/rectangle that enclose the object), you can see it by changing the object display to `Bounds`:

[image]

If you want to have the liquid stay in a shape that's not a rectangular box, you have to use a separate object set to Effector to act as a container.

For example, if you want the sphere to act as the walls of a container:

1. Duplicate it
2. Set the fluid type to Effector
3. Go into edit mode, and flip the normals so that they face inwards.
4. Back inside the simulation settings, set Is Planar, and turn up the Surface Thickness until things stop leaking

[image]

5. Put your flow source inside the sphere.
6. Bake
7. ???
8. Profit!

You should get something looking like this:

[image]

Here's the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

Consider using older versions of Blender. Older versions of blender may have shape preserving features. This effect would be for more fantasy scenes.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WruTNnF6Ztg

It is not clear that this one does.  It appears you have a domain and a source of fluid.  The fluid does not retain the shape of the source of the fluid.