# No physics collision when filling a sphere with fluid in Blender 3.2

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, collision

I can't fill a sphere with fluid when using Blender 3.2. I tried using a number of solutions from Youtube videos tutorial and from this platform, but none of them work and my fluid just drops out of the sphere like the sphere isn't even there. I already tried stating the sphere as a domain or effector. My blend can be downloaded [here](https://file.io/YW6yhrCU86dw).

[image]

I had [found](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167380/mantaflow-fluid-does-not-take-the-shape-of-a-sphere-blender-2-8) a previously related question which might help.

User `8176135` mentioned that `bounds` might help, and I discovered that apparently, the default bounds of my UV sphere is of shape `cube`. I also tried changing that bounds in `Properties Editor -> Object Tab -> Viewport Display -> Display As -> Bounds` w/ the bounds type set to `Bounds`, but the sphere still doesn't work as expected.

Some people also mentioned using the Solidify modifier to increase the width boundary. I tried increasing the modifier's strength to 50m, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I'm not sure why blender doing this,by delete the top vertex(open a hole on top of the sphere) it now works

Comment: Hi. Please don't double-post in your own thread. Edit your initial post with any changes that you might have instead.